# Adjusting figure quality in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've written some code to produce a multi-panelled figure in matplotlib. To make the figure look sharper for use in a document, I tried increasing the dpi. I found, though, that this also changed the sizes of the figure, font, lines etc., as illustrated in the following simpler example:

```
#First normal figure
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(6,6))
for i,ax in enumerate(axarr.flatten()):
    ax.plot(range(10))
    ax.set_title('title'+str(i), fontsize=10)
    ax.set_xlabel('x'+str(i), fontsize=10)
    ax.set_ylabel('y'+str(i), fontsize=10)
plt.tight_layout()

#Again, with higher dpi
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(6,6), dpi=200)
for i,ax in enumerate(axarr.flatten()):
    ax.plot(range(10))
    ax.set_title('title'+str(i), fontsize=10)
    ax.set_xlabel('x'+str(i), fontsize=10)
    ax.set_ylabel('y'+str(i), fontsize=10)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

On my computer (using matplotlib 1.4.3), the second figure is larger in size and the text is larger, so that the y-axis labels overlap. Without the use of plt.tight_layout(), the overlap of the subplot axes is also worse. Obviously, this is not helpful when just trying to make a higher quality figure. What is going on here, and how can I change the figure quality and keep the appearance of the figure constant? Is there a solution that will also work when I've adjusted subplot parameters, added colour bars and legends etc. i.e. in general? Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you show it and then you save it on the GUI window. You have to save image from command `savefig` defining there the dpi.

Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#First normal figure
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(6,6))
for i,ax in enumerate(axarr.flatten()):
    ax.plot(range(10))
    ax.set_title('title'+str(i), fontsize=10)
    ax.set_xlabel('x'+str(i), fontsize=10)
    ax.set_ylabel('y'+str(i), fontsize=10)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('myfigure_100.png', dpi=100)
plt.savefig('myfigure_200.png', dpi=200)
```

If you want to show it, you can at the end of the scrpit add `plt.show()`

**EDIT**

The relation of the dpi of figure size and the font size can be shown on the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#First normal figure
fig1, axarr1 = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(6,6), dpi=100)
for i,ax in enumerate(axarr1.flatten()):
    ax.plot(range(10))
    ax.set_title('title'+str(i), fontsize=10)
    ax.set_xlabel('x'+str(i), fontsize=10)
    ax.set_ylabel('y'+str(i), fontsize=10)
plt.tight_layout()

fig2, axarr2 = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(12,12), dpi=50)
for i,ax in enumerate(axarr2.flatten()):
    ax.plot(range(10))
    ax.set_title('title'+str(i), fontsize=20)
    ax.set_xlabel('x'+str(i), fontsize=20)
    ax.set_ylabel('y'+str(i), fontsize=20)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had meant to mention that if possible, I would prefer not to do it with savefig since I am using the same script with different argument calls to produce a large number of figures, and would need to call savefig for each one outside the script (since the filenames I'm using are not easily 'programmable'), and I find I can readily end up making mistakes like saving the wrong figure to a file if I do it this way. If I have to do something similar in the future, I might also forget about setting the dpi. Is there no way to do this without using savefig?

Comment: I'd also be very interested to understand why changing the dpi changes the plot appearance in a GUI window, if anyone knows that.

Comment: If your names are not easily programmable, make a list and pass the corresponding argument as the filename of the saved image. About the second comment, I have edited my comment to explain why changing dpi the appearance can be the same. dpi means "dot per inch", and fontsize are the points size of digits/letters. So depending how you choose them, the result can be the same.

Comment: Thanks for that. I can see then why changing the dpi in savefig is much more straightforward if there are a lot of figure elements to adjust, so I will do it that way.