# How to change DPI of my Pandas Dataframe Plot?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to change the DPI of my Pandas Dataframe Plot.

I've tried this code but doesn't give me the right result (no DPI change):

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=140)

my_data.sample(250).plot(kind="scatter", x="X data", y="Y")

plt.plot(x_data, y_hat, "r", lw=3, alpha=0.6)

plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807999/adjusting-figure-quality-in-matplotlib

Comment: Not a duplicate if you take into consideration the accepted answer - how to set DPI when running `DataFrame.plot()`, instead of plotting 'manually' from MPL.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The dataframe is not plotted to the figure of which you changed the dpi. Instead a new figure is created. To plot a dataframe to an existing figure's axes, you may use the `ax` argument.

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=140)
df.plot(..., ax = plt.gca())
```

Alternatively you may set the dpi of any figure being created using rcParams.

```
plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 140
df.plot(...)
```