How to change the resolution of a OpenStreetMaps figure?
For a little design project, I want to use some geo data from OpenStreetMaps.
Let's use the data from the little german coast village of Greetsiel for illustration of the issue.
I use the following code snippet:
import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

place_name = "Greetsiel, Germany"

# List key-value pairs for tags
tags_buildings = {'building': True}   

plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 100
buildings = ox.features_from_place(place_name, tags_buildings)
buildings.plot(figsize=(120,180), markersize=0.01, linewidth=0.01)
plt.savefig(r'C:\Users\Lepakk\Desktop\buildings.png', dpi=100)

The figure that is opened in Spyder looks like this:

Where the village is in the lower right corner, let's focus on a uniquely shaped building in the center of the village.

If i open the saved image and zoom into the respective position, it looks like this:

Now I was thinking, the bad resolution might be due to 100 dpi being just not enough. Let's change this value to
plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 1000
buildings = ox.features_from_place(place_name, tags_buildings)
buildings.plot(figsize=(120,180), markersize=0.01, linewidth=0.01)
plt.savefig(r'C:\Users\Lepakk\Desktop\buildings.png', dpi=1000)

The resolution should be ten times more now. However, the figure looks unchanged:

So, how can I change the resolution of the saved image file?
Thank you in advance!

Looks like osmnx uses geopandas data frames so I added that tag.

You would need to save the picture to a vectorized format like SVG.

OSMnx downloads the data, but you are calling the plot method of a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227792/how-to-change-dpi-of-my-pandas-dataframe-plot

This works for me, though as Tiger-222 noted in the comments, you are probably better off with svg format.  That gives a smaller file size for this example as well as cleaner images when you zoom in.
import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

place_name = "Greetsiel, Germany"

# List key-value pairs for tags
tags_buildings = {'building': True}   

plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 1000
buildings = ox.features_from_place(place_name, tags_buildings)
buildings.plot(figsize=(12, 18))
plt.savefig('osm.png')



Unfortunately, your version still doesn't change anything for me. However, saving a svg-file is a significant improvement that helps a lot.
