# using savefig to increase dots per inch (DPI) in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807999/adjusting-figure-quality-in-matplotlib) answer, suggests using plt.savefig in order to increase the DPI.  I am a relative newbie, and not sure how to use .savefig.

savefig's [call signature](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) requires fname to reference the file (or object?) which needs more DPI:

[image]

In the following code, what should I use for fname?  Should I create an object and then reference that?

```
#previous code generates two dataframes now converted to two lists...

Max_Vals = DFMAX1.tolist()
Min_Vals = DFMIN1.tolist()

fig = plt.figure()

plt.plot(Max_Vals, 'g-')
plt.plot(Min_Vals, 'b-')

fig.set_size_inches(30.,18.)
plt.show()
```

[image]

When I run savefig without fname:

```
plt.savefig(dpi=300)
```

I get an error:

[image]

Grateful for any help.

Comment: `.savefig()` does as it suggests - it saves the figure. This creates a file rather than just showing the plot in a window (e.g. `plt.show()`). I assume to get the graph shown you used `plt.show()` and then print-screen or similar?

Comment: When I run savefig without the fname paramater, I get an error.  I will edit my question to show this.

Comment: Why aren't you giving it a filename?

Comment: could you give me an example please?

Comment: Ah.  So fname can be declared in savefig.  Is that right?

Comment: `fname` is just a parameter without a default option.

Comment: thanks - basic question but... where is it saving the file to?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The point of `plt.savefig()` is it allows you to export the graph to a file. If you're just using `plt.show()` you're only *showing* the image, at which point to copy it elsewhere you have to use print-screen or similar.

Try running:

```
#previous code generates two dataframes now converted to two lists...

Max_Vals = DFMAX1.tolist()
Min_Vals = DFMIN1.tolist()

fig = plt.figure()

plt.plot(Max_Vals, 'g-')
plt.plot(Min_Vals, 'b-')

fig.set_size_inches(30.,18.)
plt.savefig('100dpi.png', dpi=100)
plt.savefig('200dpi.png', dpi=200)
```

At this point, two image files will be saved in your working folder (likely the same folder as your script) - one with 100dpi, the second with 200dpi.